# Pagination in GWT

Tags: gwt

Is pagination supported in GWT? Does GWT provide a GWT GUI element?

Answer (score 13):

If you need table pagination, you can try the GWT Widget called "CellTable". It is a customizable table which supports pagination easily.

You can find more info here (javadoc page) : http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/CellTable.html

And this is an example of how use it: 
http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

Answer (score 6):

As @caarlos0 mentioned, CellTable is a good start. You can also take a look of GWT [SimplePager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/SimplePager.html) and [AsyncDataProvider](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/view/client/AsyncDataProvider.html). Basically a SimplePager will be bind to a CellTable (or any Cell widget) and AsyncDataProvider. If there is a page change event fired (like user click next page), the onRangeChanged() will be called inside AsyncDataProvider, and you can customize the paging behavior in that function.

Answer (score 6):

I have tried pagination with Celltable and it goes fine.

In your activity, you should do something similar to this:

```java
CellTable table;

@Override
public void start(AcceptsOneWidget panel, EventBus eventBus) {
    // Get the table from the view
    view.setPresenter(this);
    panel.setWidget(view.asWidget());
    table=view.getCellTable();
    final SingleSelectionModel<Your_Class> selectionModel = new SingleSelectionModel<Your_Class>();
    table.setSelectionModel(selectionModel);
    selectionModel.addSelectionChangeHandler(
        new SelectionChangeEvent.Handler() {
            public void onSelectionChange(SelectionChangeEvent event) {
                Your_Class selected = selectionModel.getSelectedObject();
                if (selected != null) {
                    // Go to edit screen with selected.getId(); 
                }
            }
        });
}
```

Then in your implementation view create the columns:

```java
table = new CellTable<Your_Class>();
table.setSelectionModel( new SingleSelectionModel<Your_Class>());
```

And finally put the pagination:

```java
SimplePager pager;
SimplePager.Resources pagerResources = GWT.create(SimplePager.Resources.class);
pager = new SimplePager(TextLocation.CENTER, pagerResources, true, 0,true);
pager.setDisplay(table);

dataProvider.setList(list_of_data);
pager.setPageSize(number_you_want);
```

Answer (score 5):

Suggestion is that use

> Gwt-Ext or SmartGWT

which provides various components including local paging and remote paging, which can save your burning midnight oil.

Comment: I don't know about Gwt-Ext but SmartGWT is a horrible clutter. If you wish to destroy your site performance and have many confusing problems then SmartGWT is your library.

Answer (score 5):

You can extend [AbstractPager](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/AbstractPager.html) if you want to have more control over the interface than SimplePager. Then you just need to override onRangeOrRowCountChanged(). You can also implement nice things like lazy loading. You can then paginate any widget that implements HasRows.

Answer (score 4):

you always can extend a component and add features by yourself, or, like @ankit says, use smartgwt.

remember, one of gwt advantages, is the possible to add features to default components, enjoy it.

[edit]
another thing I remember now, take a look at this: http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest using celltable. It is quite complicated at first sight. But, once you are used to it its powerful. 
CellTable for multiple columns
CellList for single column
Don't try CellTree is quite buggy.

CellTable sorting and column width info:
http://code.google.com/intl/ca/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellTable.html

Answer (score 4):

yes.CellTable is really a good option for pagination.Once you get used to it.u will find it very user friendly.use simplePager for pagination.

Answer (score 4):

yes you have different different options like you use Cell Widgets of GWT , GWT-Ext , GXT for the pagination heir are some links for pagination

GWT : http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

GXT : http://extjs.com/examples/#paging

Answer (score 3):

yes. CellTable and Pager is what you want.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#Selection_Data_Paging

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using something like **Ext-GWT**. It provides built in mechanisms for handling paging.
You can have a grid view that supports **Local Pagination** (all the data is collected in one call but split into different pages) or **Remote Pagination**(data call is made each time a new page is loaded)

Answer (score 1):

**Q1 Is pagination supported in GWT?**

*Yes*

**Q2 Does GWT provide a GWT GUI element?**

*Yes*

Details -

Paging is the operation of loading and bringing into view a range of data that is not currently loaded. 
**Q1** - Client side pagination is fully supported by GWT via **SimplePager** and **AbstractPager** classes. If you are looking for remote pagination then you'll have to create your own custom widgets and logic as per your requirement.

Example :

```
public class SimplePagerExample implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
// Create a CellList.
CellList<String> cellList = new CellList<String>(new TextCell());

// Add a cellList to a data provider.
ListDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<String>();
List<String> data = dataProvider.getList();
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
  data.add("Item " + i);
}
dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellList);

// Create a SimplePager.
SimplePager pager = new SimplePager();

// Set the cellList as the display.
pager.setDisplay(cellList);

// Add the pager and list to the page.
VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
vPanel.add(pager);
vPanel.add(cellList);
RootPanel.get().add(vPanel);
      }
    }
```

`
**Q2** **SimplePager** contains the buttons and text label that you can customize as per your requirement. For reference check this link 
http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTable

[UI of simple pager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHorH.png)

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is quite old but this as not been mentioned yet. You can use a [ListDataProvider](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/view/client/ListDataProvider.html) to handle client side paging. It is very easy to use and will save you alot of time.

Answer (score 0):

Classic start/length pagination is fully supported by GWT cell widgets. Just create a SimplePager and hook the RangeChangeEvent. Your trouble will be on the server, especially with modern NoSQL databases. While most of them support "start" and "limit" query modifiers in the same manner JPA/Hibernate does, "start" is highly discouraged, because it can only work by iterating over unneeded data.

Consider continuos blog-syle "scrolling" pagination or "Prev/Next" only. Then you can implement it via sorting the result set and specifying "lee than" or "greater" conditions - together with "limit".

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.ravi.gwt.client;

import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;
import com.ravi.gwt.client.ContactDatabase.ContactInfo;
import com.ravi.gwt.client.ui.MyPaginationDataGrid;
public class GWT11 implements EntryPoint {

    public void onModuleLoad() {
        MyPaginationDataGrid<ContactInfo> grid = new MyPaginationDataGrid<ContactInfo>();
        grid.setHeight("500px");`enter code here`
        grid.setDataList(ContactDatabase.get().generateContacts(100));
        RootPanel.get().add(grid);
    }
}
```